# Not communicate with client when client on other machine

Tags: c#, tcp, server

I make a TCP/IP server in C# and client too. TCP-server is broadcasting packets to clients.

But it only broadcast on local IP not on other computers/machines.

All computers on connected SN MP server. I also changed IP address in code from (127.0.0.0) to network IP address (SNMP server IP Address). I pinged others IP with my computer; it's working but not making a connection with my TCP-server that I have made in C#.

Can you help me in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Can't give a proper answer without seeing some code, but for starters, you can check whether the port is blocked in firewall or something (try to allow incoming connections in firewall for the specific port (whitelist it) )